# Full Calendar and CakePHP 3.x cannot get events to show on calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, fullcalendar, cakephp-3.x

On the calendar I can only get the events if I hard code the json array in the events section in my ready.js file. If I use a url then they will not show.

If I browse to the url with the events it shows the json array.

Here is a sample event in the array:

```
[{"id":10,"title":"Utah REIA Monthly Meeting--Your Investor Toolbox provided with the New Website Launch","start":"2015-11-24T18:30:00-0700","end":"2015-11-24T20:30:00-0700","allDay":false,"url":"\/events\/view\/10","details":"\u003Cp\u003E\u003Cspan\u003EAre you a real estate investor who is looking for\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/p\u003E\n\u003Col\u003E\n\t\u003Cli\u003EMore education\u003C\/li\u003E\n\t\u003Cli\u003EIndividuals to connect and network with\u003C\/li\u003E\n\t\u003Cli\u003EDiscounts and special offers from retailers you frequent most\u003C\/li\u003E\n\u003C\/ol\u003E\n\n\u003Cp\u003E\u003Cspan\u003EThe Utah REIA has listened and has created a custom website to meet the needs of the real estate investor. This new website will:\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/p\u003E\n\u003Col\u003E\n\t\u003Cli\u003EShowcase discounts and special offers from favorite retailers including, but not limited to, Home Depot, Office Max, and Western Reporting.\u003C\/li\u003E\n\t\u003Cli\u003EProvide access to meeting videos and Powerpoint presentations dating back to the inception of the Utah REIA\u003C\/li\u003E\n\t\u003Cli\u003EAllow for Vendors to customize Business Directory listings as well as provide access to post special discounts and incentives\u003C\/li\u003E\n\t\u003Cli\u003EContinue to provide access\u003Cspan class=\u0022text_exposed_show\u0022\u003E to the Utah REIA Library--an archive of 27 folders filled with publications surrounding topics including, but are not limited to 1031 Exchanges, Foreclosures, Forms & Contracts, and Business Management.\u003C\/li\u003E\n\t\u003Cli\u003EProvide a way to connect easily with members of the Utah REIA\u003C\/li\u003E\n\u003C\/ol\u003E\n\n\u003Cp\u003ECome and learn how all of this works so that you can take advantage of these amazing tools as well as provide us with feedback to help us help meet your needs better!\u003C\/p\u003E","className":"Blue"}]
```

If I copy that array and place it in my js file it will show the events, but not if I use the url.

Ready.js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left:   'title',
            center: '',
            right:  'today agendaDay,agendaWeek,month prev,next'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        scrollTime: "08:00:00",
        aspectRatio: 2,
        editable: adminEdit,
        events: plgFcRoot + 'events/feed',
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.qtip({
                content: event.details,
                position: { 
                    target: 'mouse',
                    adjust: {
                        x: 10,
                        y: -5
                    }
                },
                style: {
                    name: 'light',
                    tip: 'leftTop'
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with Full Calendar, so here's just a tip to maybe get you started: Check your browsers network and log consoles, and look for possible errors. Also, for future questions, try to choose more appropriate tags (retagging it hours later wont gain much attention anymore), using 3 CakePHP version tags isn't helpful, you better chose just one version related one, and use others to further specify the used techniques, that way it's more likely that you'll get help from people that know about the software that you are using.

Comment: @ndm thank you for the tip. I have checked the console, network, and files under logs folder for cake and have no related errors or warning.

Answer (score 0):

I was using $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler'); in my App Controller and this was enabling data views for the whole application and caused the events not to render. I took that out of my App Controller and it is now displaying the events.